# Java - c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1) does not work

Tags: java, calendar, addition

Could you please explain why the below code  failed at

```
c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
```

The input is getListOfDatesBwTwoDates("01/01/2020", "06/15/2020","mm/dd/yyyy");
**No error returned but the list returned is only [01/01/2020];**
I tried but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Do you not get an error message that is supposed to be posted here?

Comment: Hi, I just edit the question.The input is getListOfDatesBwTwoDates("01/01/2020", "06/15/2020","mm/dd/yyyy"); but the list returned is only [01/01/2020];

Comment: No error is returned but it seems the c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1) does not work so the while loop stop after 1st of execution.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is here :

```
getListOfDatesBwTwoDates("01/01/2020", "06/15/2020","mm/dd/yyyy");
```

You should used

```
getListOfDatesBwTwoDates("01/01/2020", "06/15/2020","**MM**/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: "MM/dd/yyyy" , that's the right pattern format

Comment: I tested your code in my IDE and it worked.

Comment: Do you mean my code or the code after using the new pattern here

Comment: After using the new pattern